# How to register a signal handler as a class method?

Tags: c++, signals, boost-bind

Suppose I have a `class A`, with a public method `void f(int sig)`. In constructor of `A` I added

```
signal(SIGSEV, boost::bind(&A::f, this, _1));
```

This returns compilation error

```
error : cannot convert `boost::_bi::bind_t<void, boost::_mfi::mf1<void, A, int>, boost::_bi::list2<boost::_bi::value<A*>, boost::arg<1> > >' to `__sighandler_t {aka void (*)(int)}' for argument `2' to `void (* signal(int, __sighandler_t))(int)'
```

Any idea why?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Being a C function, `signal` can only take a plain function pointer, not arbitrary callable types. You'll need a non-member wrapper function, and a global variable to store `this`, in order to call a member function from a signal handler.

```
static A * signal_object;
extern "C" void signal_handler(int signum) {signal_object->f(signum);}

// later...
signal_object = this;
signal(SIGSEGV, signal_handler);
```

Comment: Right. Just for completeness this function can be a class static method too.

Comment: So if somehow the signal function was compiled with a C++ compiler then what the OP tried to do at first would work fine?

Comment: @LanPac: No, the handler argument for `signal` must be a function pointer, and the result of `boost::bind` is something else (in this case, a class type containing a member-function pointer and a copy of the `this` pointer, with an overloaded `operator()` to invoke it).